# sorting algorithm implementation in c

Tags: c, sorting

in order to sort an array in ascending order, i thought of the following:

```
#define SIZE 10 //as an example

void swapValues(int *x, int *y)
{
    int temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

void sort(int *array)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE-1; i++) {
        for(j = i + 1; j < SIZE; j++) {

            if(array[i] > array[j]) {
                swapValues( (array+i) , (array+j) );
            }

        }
    }
}
```

the function works, but after taking a look on 
[this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms), i'm a bit curious, this looks like a bubble sort algorithm, but it isn't, so:

1. is this function an implementation of an already known sorting algorithm?
2. how would this function fare in comparison to other simple sorting algorithms like bubble sort or selection sort?

Comment: you might find this interesting:  [15 sorting algorithms shown visually](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPRA0W1kECg)

Comment: I'm not sure why you think this isn't a bubble sort.  It looks like a bubble sort to me. In any event this is an Order - N squared sort, and it fares poorly against the best of sortsi.

Comment: I would call this a selection sort. Still n-squared, so no better than a bubble.

Comment: @Leonard i thought the same thing in the beginning, i doubt it's a bubble sort because the function starts with a value and compares the whole array against it and then it increments, where in bubble sort you just compare two adjacent values and swap, but i might be mistaken, hence the question

Comment: Why do you think your algorithm is not a bubble sort?  It isn't a selection sort, in my book, but it may be that my book isn't the same as other people's.  Whatever the name of the sub-species of sort, it is a quadratic sorting algorithm (O(N²) in Big-O notation), and therefore not very efficient on big data sets.  It isn't worth spending much time optimizing it; there are better algorithms with O(N.logN) complexity that can be used instead.

Comment: You should have a size argument, not a `SIZE` constant. Also `array+i` and `array[i]` are two sides of the same coin.

Comment: @tadman yeah you're right about the parameter, i just made it a constant to illustrate, as for array+i see my edit and function swapValues

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker i think you're right! after looking for selection sort i found this [link](https://visualgo.net/en/sorting), it resembles the sorting behaviour of this function

Comment: You're correct; this isn't bubblesort. It's selection sort (albeit backward from the traditional mechanics of that algorithm). A bubblesort indeed compares adjacent elements scanning one direction, and after each pass, the next extreme value has been "bubbled" and the next pass will be reduced one slot to exclude it. It also has a benefit of termination detection. If any sequence pass results in *no swaps*, the sequence must be sorted and the algorithm is terminated. This means bubblesort has best-case O(n) on an already sorted sequence.

Comment: That `swapValues` function is pointless. Just do it in the loop. You don't need to abstract out the obvious.

Comment: @WhozCraig does the fact that bubble sort has a better best-case O(n) compared to this algorithm mean that bubble sort is better? since both have average and worst case of O(n²)?

Comment: or generally speaking, if there is two sorting algorithms of the same complexity, how can we know which one performance is better?

Comment: @WhozCraig This is indeed a selection sort, but the primary thing that's backward is the missing optimization of one swap per outer loop.  Typically, this runs faster than bubblesort, but is not a stable sort.  When sorting structs instead of ints, this can matter.  The reason to know this sort (with optimizations) is that at most (n-1) swaps can be more important that O(n log n) compares in a small sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation is using selection sort. It's not bubble sort. Since in bubble sort we compare two consecutive elements at once, therefore this isn't it. This is selection sort where in you compare one element with the rest of elements at a time in an array, and swap accordingly.